# Force two elements to have the same width

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2, buefy

I'm trying to force two `b-buttons` (button component from `Buefy`) to stay as large as the wider one of them.

I believe that I need to set the min-width of one button to the width value of the other. In that way, if one button grows larger, the other one should grow too.

*Now, how could I do that?*

My first take was to set a bind to the 'min-width' style for each button, like so:

```
<b-button ref="firstButton" type="is-primary" size="is-large"
      :style="{ 'min-width': $refs.secondButton !== undefined ? $refs.secondButton.$el.clientWidth + 'px' : 0 }">
    First Button
</b-button> 

<b-button ref="secondButton" type="is-primary" size="is-large"
      :style="{ 'min-width': $refs.firstButton !== undefined ? $refs.firstButton.$el.clientWidth + 'px' : 0 }">
    Second Button
</b-button>
```

But that barely works, looks like it works once at page render and any change in size (due to localization, for example) is ignored. Looks like there's no reactivity in that `$ref`.

My second take involved a computed property, same idea as the previous take, but instead of setting the style inline, set to a computed property.

But this time, the `$ref` elements are undefined, looks like the computation happens before they are set.

How can I make my two buttons to be the same width, without setting a fixed value, and being able to resize as the buttons increase/decrease in size?

#### Here's the whole code:

(it's just two buttons surrounded by a hero section)

```
<template>
    <div>
        <section class="hero is-primary is-bold is-relative">
            <div class="hero-body">
                <div class="section">
                    <div class="container">
                        <!-- $refs.secondButton !== undefined ? $refs.secondButton.$el.clientWidth + 'px' : 0 -->
                        <!-- $refs.firstButton !== undefined ? $refs.firstButton.$el.clientWidth + 'px' : 0 -->

                        <div class="columns is-centered is-multiline is-mobile">
                            <div class="column is-narrow has-text-centered">
                                <b-button ref="firstButton" type="is-primary" size="is-large"
                                    :style="{ 'min-width': $refs.secondButton !== undefined ? $refs.secondButton.$el.clientWidth + 'px' : 0 }">
                                    First Button
                                </b-button>
                            </div>

                            <div class="column is-narrow has-text-centered">
                                <b-button ref="secondButton" type="is-primary" size="is-large"
                                    :style="{ 'min-width': $refs.firstButton !== undefined ? $refs.firstButton.$el.clientWidth + 'px' : 0 }">
                                    Second Button
                                </b-button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {

    }
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
    //All from Buefy and Bulma.
</style>
```

Comment: where is your css?

Comment: I think you can create property and control their width with it. So they always will be same width

Comment: @Dejan.S It's all from Buefy/Bulma. I'm not using custom CSS. Anyway, it's not that relevant, since all it does is to centralize the two buttons and add some margin.

Comment: @AsiPle Not sure. My issue is to get the the width of the buttons as they change in size due to localization.

Comment: You can change property due to localization and buttons will be changed to. Maybe you are trying to say that they have width due to content inside and you need to set width of the longest button to another?

Comment: @AsiPle Yes, if the button content changes, the button width will change too. I need to keep both buttons width in sync. Setting the largest width to the width of the smallest, making both the same size.

Comment: @NickeManarin How about re-calculating the widths as the localization change triggers?

Comment: @YomS. I'm using `vue-i18n`. I'm going to check if there's any trigger that I can use. But it would be easier if I could "watch" the width of the button directly.

Comment: @NickeManarin When you said "keeping them in sync", do you mean these two buttons will have the same content?

Comment: @YomS. No, just the width.

Comment: Does not really matter if you are using "insert css framework". I can give you custom css, but I'm not gone spend time on giving you a solution from scratch if you can't make the efftort in making working solution for us. If I also give you a solution I don't know if that is gone interfer with other css you have. So again, you are better of making a working example.

Comment: @Dejan.S No need to. I already figured it out. I included a working example on my answer, CSS included (but it was the CSS that already came with the sandbox).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set style to **ref** like that because in Vue lifecycle, ref is only **available** after **mounted**.

You can add the JS code to change the width of the button in **mounted hook**

```
                    <div class="columns is-centered is-multiline is-mobile">
                        <div class="column is-narrow has-text-centered">
                            <b-button ref="firstButton" type="is-primary" size="is-large">
                                First Button
                            </b-button>
                        </div>

                        <div class="column is-narrow has-text-centered">
                            <b-button ref="secondButton" type="is-primary" size="is-large">
                                Second Button
                            </b-button>
                        </div>
                    </div>


  mounted() {
    let firstWidth = this.$refs.firstButton.clientWidth;
    let secondWidth = this.$refs.secondButton.clientWidth;
    if (firstWidth > secondWidth) {
      this.$refs.secondButton.style.width = firstWidth + "px";
    } else {
      this.$refs.firstButton.style.width = secondWidth + "px";
    }
  }
```

And also, I'm not sure about this but you may need to add `display: inline-block` to b-button if the current display type css of b-button ignore the size setting

```
b-button {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: You need to set the style by accessing the `$el` property inside the `button` like this: `this.$refs.secondButton.$el.style`. Also, this code does not update the size when the text inside the buttons change. Also x2, To work, you need to set the value to `minWidth` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to work out the issue by creating two methods, with two nested `$nextTick()` calls inside. After, you just set the methods to the style prop of each button.

```
 <div class="column is-narrow has-text-centered">
     <b-button ref="firstButton" type="is-light" size="is-large"
              :style="{ 'min-width':  getMinWidthFirst() }">
         {{ firstText }}
     </b-button>
 </div>

<div class="column is-narrow has-text-centered">
    <b-button ref="secondButton" type="is-light" size="is-large"
              :style="{ 'min-width': getMinWidthSecond() }">
        {{ secondText }}
    </b-button>
</div>
```

Here are the methods, they are called automatically when the text is changing:

```
getMinWidthFirst() {
  var size = this.$refs.secondButton !== undefined
      ? this.$refs.secondButton.$el.clientWidth + 2 + "px"
      : 0;

  this.$nextTick().then(() => {
    this.$refs.firstButton.$el.style.minWidth = 0 + "px";

    this.$nextTick().then(() => {
      this.$refs.firstButton.$el.style.minWidth =
        this.$refs.secondButton.$el.clientWidth + 2 + "px";
    });
  });

  return size;
},
getMinWidthSecond() {
  var size = this.$refs.firstButton !== undefined
      ? this.$refs.firstButton.$el.clientWidth + 2 + "px"
      : 0;

  this.$nextTick().then(() => {
    this.$refs.secondButton.$el.style.minWidth = 0 + "px";

    this.$nextTick().then(() => {
      this.$refs.secondButton.$el.style.minWidth =
        this.$refs.firstButton.$el.clientWidth + 2 + "px";
      });
  });

  return size;
}
```

The idea of using two nested calls to the `$nextTick` is that with just one call the button would not reduce in width of the text was small.

#### Working solution:

https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-r4fp1?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue:1679-2622

[image: A 97.1Kb gif showcasing the solution]
*(A 97KB gif showcasing the solution)*